# Can't find driver for my wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I'm pretty new to Linux, and need help with installing a driver. Currently, my computer has an internal WiFi adapter that can only connect to 2.4 GHz, so I bought one of those small WiFi adapters that you plug into your USB (here's the link to it: [https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Netw.../dp/B00W5UHQ8M](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W5UHQ8M)). This one let's me connect to 5.0 GHz which would  increase my WiFi speed from about 10 Mbps to around 150 Mbps. It works great on my Windows installation (I have Linux dual-booted). When I installed the driver on Windows I noticed an option for Linux, so I'm pretty sure I could get this to work. On the CD that came with it I found two files that might have the drivers in it; one is a tar.bz2 and one is a .zip. The problem is, I can't seem to figure it out how to actually get it to install. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks again!

Edit:
Here's what I got from running lsusb:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23114097/

Comment: If you only pay for 10Mbps of internet, you will not get 150Mbps to the world.

Comment: @KazWolfe with all due respect the question wasn't how to purchase a bandwidth upgrade from his/her ISP.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm aware. I'm just making sure the OP knows that he's aware that he may actually gain zero benefit from upgrading his card, which is probably already complaint with Wireless-N

Comment: @KazWolfe His/Her $15 no-name dongle looks like a waste of time. Single band 2.4Ghz seems to work best for most people rather than dual band 2.4/5 anyway based on the last time I researched the topic. I think I bought like 4 dongles/usb antenna/mini-pcie cards for the old Toshiba laptop trying to increase speed and in the end went back to the old Intel 3495 or whatever it was the machine was sold with. In the end stability was better than number appeal.

Comment: Well I tried installing a game in steam which normally takes about 5-10 minutes to install on Windows (while connected to 5 GHz) took me several hours while connected to the 2.4. I've tested the dongle on Windows and it works wonderfully.

Comment: Silly me, I think we should gather some useful data and *actually try to help!!!* Please insert the device and open a terminal and run: `lsusb` Next, edit the question to add the result.

Comment: Alright, I added it to the question, I believe the MediaTek Inc. is the one I need the driver for.